# Drill down to grouped column level

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

Here's my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6LXVQ/1223/

What I'd like to be able to do is drill down to a second level, and that level also be grouped columns. Right now, if you drill into any of the top level columns, you get single columns on the second level. Any ideas?

My current code:

$(function() {

```
  // Create the chart
  $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Basic drilldown'
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
      },

      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },

      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          borderWidth: 0,
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
          }
        }
      },

      series: [{
        'name': 'ROI',
        'data': [{
          "name": "USA",
          "level": 1,
          "parent": "",
          "y": 0.629820585402,
          "drilldown": "12000"
        }]
      }, {
        'name': 'BOI',
        'data': [{
          "name": "USA",
          "level": 1,
          "parent": "",
          "y": 3.29620816518,
          "drilldown": "12000"
        }]
      }],
      drilldown: {
        series: [{
            "id": "12000",
            "name": "USA",
            "data": [{
              "name": "a",
              "level": 2,
              "parent": "12000",
              "y": null,
              "drilldown": "12400"
            }, {
              "name": "b",
              "level": 2,
              "parent": "12000",
              "y": null,
              "drilldown": "12300"
            }, {
              "name": "c",
              "level": 2,
              "parent": "12000",
              "y": 1,
              "drilldown": "12200"
            }, {
              "name": "d",
              "level": 2,
              "parent": "12000",
              "y": null,
              "drilldown": "12500"
            }, {
              "name": "e",
              "level": 2,
              "parent": "12000",
              "y": 4,
              "drilldown": "12100"
            }, {
              "name": "f",
              "level": 2,
              "parent": "12000",
              "y": null,
              "drilldown": "12600"
            }]
          }, {
            "id": "12400",
            "name": "a",
            "data": [{
              "name": "g",
              "level": 3,
              "parent": "12400",
              "y": [1, 2],
              "drilldown": "12410"
            }, {
              "name": "h",
              "level": 3,
              "parent": "12400",
              "y": [2, 3],
              "drilldown": "12430"
            }, {
              "name": "i",
              "level": 3,
              "parent": "12400",
              "y": [1, 2],
              "drilldown": "12420"
            }, {
              "name": "j",
              "level": 3,
              "parent": "12400",
              "y": [2, 3],
              "drilldown": "12410"
            }, {
              "name": "k",
              "level": 3,
              "parent": "12400",
              "y": null,
              "drilldown": "12430"
            }, {
              "name": "l",
              "level": 3,
              "parent": "12400",
              "y": null,
              "drilldown": "12420"
            }]
          }, {
            "id": "12300",
            "name": "b",
            "data": [{
              "name": "m",
              "level": 3,
              "parent": "12300",
              "y": null,
              "drilldown": "12310"
            }, {
              "name": "n",
              "level": 3,
              "parent": "12300",
              "y": null,
              "drilldown": "12310"
            }]
          }, {
            "id": "12200",
            "name": "c",
            "data": [{
              "name": "o",
              "level": 3,
              "parent": "12200",
              "y": null,
              "drilldown": "12220"
            }, {
              "name": "p",
              "level": 3,
              "parent": "12200",
              "y": 0.757404909208,
              "drilldown": "12210"
            }, {
              "name": "q",
              "level": 3,
              "parent": "12200",
              "y": null,
              "drilldown": "12230"
            }, {
              "name": "r",
              "level": 3,
              "parent": "12200",
              "y": null,
              "drilldown": "12220"
            }, {
              "name": "w",
              "level": 3,
              "parent": "12200",
              "y": 0.757404909208,
              "drilldown": "12210"
            }, {
              "name": "t",
              "level": 3,
              "parent": "12200",
              "y": null,
              "drilldown": "12230"
            }]
          }, {
            "id": "12500",
            "name": "d",
            "data": [{
              "name": "v",
              "level": 3,
              "parent": "12500",
              "y": null,
              "drilldown": "12510"
            }, {
              "name": "w",
              "level": 3,
              "parent": "12500",
              "y": null,
              "drilldown": "12510"
            }]
          }]
        }
      })
  });
```

Comment: Hi, So you would like to have functionality similar to this Highcharts demo?
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/multi-series/ 
Or maybe something similar to this option? 
http://jsfiddle.net/49q18Lp3/6/